# How to store Keystore using userPKCS12 in LDAP?

Tags: java, ldap, keystore

I got a java keystore which I want to store in LDAP using userPKCS12 attribute. I already transfered the JKS keystore to PKCS12

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /opt/tomcat/conf/.keystore -destkeystore /tmp/tomcat.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

How do I proceed to finally get the entries of this keystore into my LDIF-file?

```
dn: cn=$name,$cn
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetorgPerson
description: $name
cn: $name
sn: $name
userPKCS12;binary:: MIIQoAIBAzCCEFoGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCEEsEghBHMIIQQzCCCfAGCSqGSIb3DQEH
 AaCCCeEEggndMIIJ2TCCCdUGCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIJgjCCCX4wKAYKKoZIhvcN
 AQwBAzAaBBQJgfNb/kt83JjEL34s/vE5pFjL0wICBAAEgglQ0DQ23QhylRz4uvMr
 lleD94JSA6hdpLjsee3zxqxsPXgyz1CtsY159vw4F6rSHeSDaILve8g2w/nA0KPH
 V/QbsbAU6/g8tvqBGbbLJFbe20m9ZhAOeohPdLzT54SViJ8b3VvZf5rWCidUaYQu
 7yNqjkXAbuezRxf3TMEuR9BNQV+DWLjvNmiMGN3b1rQ0jFZHKk1VJnb6OUn63UUT
 dRun7OUdi9zR4WM7yKy0VNmC3xaI630PABibIACMdGaQGprQM6HrchkxP2M3D5jm
 8UwCkEYazd7eKyKiAEEMnK5o3nKYWbd+NmELssendiEoi3ztrLTZnEdIwUc9wA3/
 yJgcptUjzbh/2NwKdyO21Snj9iGWyw90KqI3hfL1HqiYKjF+sZ9nudxFLwbmYi0Y
.....
```

Gives this error:

```
ldapadd -h 10.1.0.99 -D cn=Directory\ Manager -w - -f action.ldif
Enter bind password: 
adding new entry cn=abcd,dc=Example,dc=com
ldap_add: Undefined attribute type
ldap_add: additional info: Entry cn=abcd,dc=Example,dc=com can not be added because BER encoding of userPKCS12 attribute is not supported
```

Solutions for bash scripts are preferred.

Thanks and regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Binary Data in LDIF**

Binary data in LDIF files is simply Base64 encoded (see [RFC 2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849)):

```
userPKCS12:: MIIJtgIBAzCCCXAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCCWEEggldMIIJWTCCBW4GCSqGSIb3DQEHA
 CCBV8EggVbMIIFVzCCBVMGCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIE+jCCBPYwKAYKKoZIhvcNAQwBAzAaBBT3WG
 ...
```

RFC 2849 explicitly states that line breaks are not required:

> 10. When an attrval-spec, distinguishedName, or rdn is base64-
>     encoded, the encoding rules specified in [5] are used with the
>     following exceptions:  a) The requirement that base64 output
>     streams must be represented as lines of no more than 76
>     characters is removed. Lines in LDIF files may only be folded
>     according to the folding rules described in note 2, above.

That being said, I have never seen an LDIF file where long lines were not folded. So, it might be a good idea to add line breaks after 76 characters anyway, just for compatibility reasons.

Rules for folding lines in LDIF are:

> 2. Any non-empty line, including comment lines, in an LDIF file
>    MAY be folded by inserting a line separator (SEP) and a SPACE.
>    Folding MUST NOT occur before the first character of the line.
>    In other words, folding a line into two lines, the first of
>    which is empty, is not permitted. Any line that begins with a
>    single space MUST be treated as a continuation of the previous
>    (non-empty) line. When joining folded lines, exactly one space
>    character at the beginning of each continued line must be
>    discarded. Implementations SHOULD NOT fold lines in the middle
>    of a multi-byte UTF-8 character.

**References to External Files**

Binary data must not necessarily be included in the LDIF file as a Base64 string. Instead a reference to an external file can be used. Example from [RFC 2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849):

```
jpegphoto:< file:///usr/local/directory/photos/fiona.jpg
```

**Transfer Option ";binary"**

The binary option ";binary" is specified in [RFC 4522](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4522), it affects the transfer of data between LDAP client and server (not the storage on the LDAP server). When it is set, the attribute is encoded according to the Basic Encoding Rules (BER).

Whether ";binary" is required for "userPKCS12" depends on the LDAP server. For example with OpenLDAP ";binary" does not work, because the syntax of "userPKCS12" is binary (and not a special syntax for PKCS#12).

**Conversion of Binary Data to Base64**

There are many ways to convert the PKCS#12 file to Base64 and you did not write if you have to do this programmatically or with command line tools. Some options are:

- OpenSSL: `openssl enc -e -base64 -in tomcat.p12 -out tomcat.b64`
- Java with Bouncy Castle: [Base64.encode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091424/return-p12-file-to-client-without-creating-keystore-file/33122790#33122790)
- Some LDAP servers like Sun Directory Server, 389 or RedHat Directory Server include a command line tool named "*ldif*" that does exactly what you want: `ldif -b "userPKCS12" < tomcat.p12 >> p12.ldif`

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited my question and added my final LDIF file and the error I get. For me it looks quite normal but my LDAP server has a different opinion ;)

Comment: @Daniel Which LDAP server are using? ";binary" might also be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I'm using OpenDS 2.2.1 as LDAP server. Unfortunately I can't upgrade or change the version

Comment: @Daniel The version does not matter, but LDAP servers behave differently when it comes to binary transfer encoding. I have updated my answer. Just try it without ";binary".

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try tomorrow (European time) as I have no access to the server at the moment.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I totally forgot about file references in LDIF files (see updated answer). Might be much easier to do it that way.

Comment: I tried it without ";binary" which gives me anything but no useful information after reading from LDAP. File references are no options because I want to store the whole keystore given the case my container is broken somehow corrupted, so I can simply restore the keystore without changing the certificate on X hosts referencing to the broken one

Comment: @Daniel Using a file reference in a LDIF file simply means that you do not have to do the Base64 encoding. It does not affect the storage of the file in the LDAP server. As for the binary option: Does this mean the import worked now without errors?

Comment: Unfortunately not. When I'm adding the content of the .p12 file directly to my LDIF file it can't be read from LDAP afterwards. Regarding the file reference:
It would look like `userPKCS12:< file:/tmp/tomcat.p12` right? If this is the case it can be added to LDAP and has this value using OpenDS Directory Manager "< file:/tmp/tomcat.p12"

Comment: @Daniel Well, it works for me. Seems like we are using different "ldapadds". Also, this seems more and more like a problem specific to OpenDS.

Comment: It may be that this kind of error is specific to OpenDS. Nevertheless thank you very very much for your help